# Can a child flow be triggered when the parent object is being updated?

Tags: visual-workflow

I got a flow on the Contact object that runs whenever a record is created/updated. However, I can't seem to get the flow to trigger whenever Contact.Account.RecordType changes. Seeing as the account itself is the one being changed, I understand that the flow itself won't run because no "change" was made to the contact object. However, I got a condition (see below) to listen for changes on the Account Record type:

[image: contact image] [image: account record change]

The flow does not when when I go to Contact.Account and manually update the record type. can I make the child flow run when the parent field changes?

Comment: See my answer, what is your goal here? Probably it can be achieved differently than you are thinking about it.

Comment: Isn't it pretty clear what I wish to achieve? I need the contact flow to react to changes in the record type on the parent object (account in this case)

Answer (score 0):

No. The flow gets triggered **only** when the record is updated/inserted/deleted, and only after that there is the checking of the conditions you've specified. So any update to the parent account **won't** trigger directly the record triggered flow on contact.

Comment: What's your solution

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. Whatever you want to achieve in contact flow on account's record type need to be done in account flow/trigger.

Based on your flow and condition added just assuming, if you have a scenario like if account's record type is changed and some changes has happened with contact as well in the same transaction then you want to perform some operation, then I would suggest get all account's Id from account trigger in a set variable and passed it to future/Queueable and perform the operation that you wanted to do in contact flow.